# Returning an array using offset function in excel?

Tags: excel, dataframe

I am unsure how to get this array... Maybe offset is the wrong function for this. But I want to return an array based on multiple criteria. Here are the two datasets it's based off of:
[image]

Basically, I would want the output to give me an array that, when entering a date, it would return what is in DataSet 2, but also on the condition that it is "In Stock" as shown in DataSet 1

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$C$3,MATCH(A10,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$50000,0),MATCH(A3,Sheet1!$B$1:$BX$1,0))
```

I know the following formula would just give me the number of apples in stock on that date, but I am unsure how to add an IF statement that checks to see if it is in stock, as well as being able to return an array instead of a single value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OFFSET is volatile and should be avoided if possible.

With TEXTJOIN we can do:

```
="["&TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,FILTER(INDEX(E:G,MATCH(A9,D:D,0),0),INDEX(B2:B4,MATCH(E1:G1,A2:A4,0))="In Stock"))&"]"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
[image: sample file]

We are going to use two `FILTER` invocations. First for rows (based on **Ref. Date**) and then for columns. In order to select the columns you can consider two options:

Manually as we did in `K2`:

```
 {1,0,1}
```

so we indicate with an 1x3 array the columns we want to consider.

Or calculated as we did in cell `K6`:

```
=FILTER(FILTER(E3:G6,D3:D6=I2),TRANSPOSE(IF(B2:B4="In Stock",1,0)))
```

The portion of the formula to build column selector is:

```
TRANSPOSE(IF(B2:B4="In Stock",1,0))
```

We evaluate the **DataSet 1** to identify which fruit are in stock (the order of the **DataSet 1** should be the same as the columns in **DataSet 2**). We need to build a column-wise array, so we `TRANSPOSE`. The result returns the same column-wise vector we put on first `K2` cell manually, i.e.: `{1,0,1}`.

If you want exactly to show the output as follow: `[1,7]`, then you can combine the previous analysis as it is on cell `K10`:

```
="["& TEXTJOIN(",", ,FILTER(FILTER(E3:G6,D3:D6=I2),
  TRANSPOSE(IF(B2:B4="In Stock",1,0)))) &"]"
```